# WCF: how to consume a self host service from internet?

Tags: wcf

I have a self host service in a WPF application and a client. It works fine if the client and the service are in the same LAN, so I can send messages from client to the service.

However, I would like to know how I can consume the service from internet.

I open the TCP ports for the listing port and the mex in my router in the NAT section and I have disabled my firewall of windows (I am working in a virtual windows xp).

I am trying to use net.tcp binding, is my first option, but also I am trying with wsHttpBinding and the problem is the same, I can send message in the LAN but I can't from internet.

Perhaps it's because I don't know how to configure the address in the service or in the client, or something like that.

Thanks you very much.
Daimroc.

EDIT1: if I use the www.canyouseeme.org the can access to my service. If I stop my service then i get an error. So it looks like that the service is visible. Then why can't send messages from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on a LAN, it is very likely that the machine that is hosting the WCF service is not assigned an IP address accessible from the Internet. For example, if the machine has an IP address starting with 10... or 172... or 192... then that is an internally assigned IP address.

Your machine must be set up to use an IP address assigned by a registrar and optionally, assigned a domain name (e.g. canyouseeme.org) so the Internet DNS servers can translate it to the assigned IP address.

Comment: You're mixing up IP routing and DNS here, I think. Just a little bit. I don't think he will be able to do anything with this answer...

Comment: Well, I am reading about my router, and it looks like that it does not support local loopback, so I can access to service with the public IP if I am trying to connect with the service from the LAN.

So I will try it with someone out of my LAN.